# Отловить сообщения в телеграм боте

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Подскажите пожалуйста как отловить сообщение которое не распознано не вызывая ошибки и не останавливая приложение, к примеру отловить в `def next`, for использовать обязательно

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def first(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,False)                 
    keyboard.add('Как тебя зовут ?')
    keyboard.add('Просто кнопка ')
    keyboard.add('Назад')
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет мой друг' ,reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send,next)


def next(message):
    if message.text == 'Назад':
        cancel(message)
    for name in ['Как тебя зовут ?']:
       if message.text == name:                
            keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,False)
            keyboard.add('Олег', 'Вася')
            keyboard.add('Главное меню')
            send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вот список моих имен' ,reply_markup=keyboard)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(send,first)


def cancel(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,False)                 
    keyboard.add('Как тебя зовут ?')
    keyboard.add('Назад')
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Давай попробуем заново' ,reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send,next)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: почему нельзя использовать `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`и рулить ответами через `if\elif`, слова\сообщения поместить в список\словарь, а всё иное через `else`? и зачем вообще цикл?

Comment: потому что есть некий словарь где очень много данных, вопросов и ответов и циклом они перебираются и создаются кнопки и т д, по этому циклом проще мне кажется реализовать